# Insert Sheet Columns is greyed out in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I want to insert a column in excel 2007, yet the insert column is greyed out

the sheet it not protected, and there is not restrictions whatsoever

another sheet on the same file work correctly.

how do I fix this?

Comment: What steps are you taking to insert a column?  Are there any merged cells?  Those can sometimes interfere with column/row operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..

Apparently, If do conditional formatting it will stretch to all columns.. And if all columns are used there is no room to insert more columns..

once the useless columns are deleted it is solved..

Answer (score 0):

Another trick which worked for me

Delete Excel12.xlb file from C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel